# codeigniter resize image and create thumbnail

Tags: php, codeigniter, resize, gd

hi according to the ci document you can resize images with image_lib and there are options that suggest we can create additional thumbnail from that image

```
create_thumb    FALSE   TRUE/FALSE (boolean)    Tells the image processing function to create a thumb.  R
thumb_marker    _thumb  None    Specifies the thumbnail indicator. It will be inserted just before the file extension, so mypic.jpg would become mypic_thumb.jpg    R
```

so here is my code

```
        $config_manip = array(
            'image_library' => 'gd2',
            'source_image'  => "./uploads/avatar/tmp/{$this->input->post('new_val')}",
            'new_image'     => "./uploads/avatar/{$this->input->post('new_val')}",
            'maintain_ratio'=> TRUE ,
            'create_thumb'  => TRUE ,
            'thumb_marker'  => '_thumb' ,
            'width'         => 150,
            'height'        => 150 
        );

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config_manip);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
```

i would assume this code resizes my image and also creates a thumbnail , but i only get one image with specified dimensions and _tump postfix

i've also tried to add this code to create second image manually but still it doesn't work and i get only one image

```
            $this->image_lib->clear();

$config_manip['new_image'] = 
"./uploads/avatar/thumbnail_{$this->input->post('new_val')}";

            $config_manip['width']     = 30 ;
            $config_manip['height']    = 30 ;
            $this->load->library('image_lib', $config_manip);
            $this->image_lib->resize();
```

Comment: What result do you want? You want to modify the original size, then create a 30x30 thumb image?

Comment: actually my original image is in the temp folder for security reasons i want to create a resized one and a thumbnail from that in my avatar folder

Comment: Those 2 part of codes looks to do the trick if you remove the `create_thumb`. I didn't know you could run functions inside `"{}"`?

Comment: What does $this->image_lib->display_errors(); return on the second resize operation?

Comment: @rbaker86 first one goes without an error but for the second one if i use $this->image_lib->clear(); i get : "Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image" which is weird cuz i have gd and it works on the first one

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It seems path is the issue in your code. I modified and tested myself it works.

```
public function do_resize()
{
    $filename = $this->input->post('new_val');
    $source_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/uploads/avatar/tmp/' . $filename;
    $target_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/uploads/avatar/';
    $config_manip = array(
        'image_library' => 'gd2',
        'source_image' => $source_path,
        'new_image' => $target_path,
        'maintain_ratio' => TRUE,
        'create_thumb' => TRUE,
        'thumb_marker' => '_thumb',
        'width' => 150,
        'height' => 150
    );
    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config_manip);
    if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    }
    // clear //
    $this->image_lib->clear();
}
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks!!

Comment: thanx but i can't use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']  , im running the application on the local and this is the address that i get :  C:/wamp/www/uploads/avatar/tmp/500419bfe5d98.jpg   which is wrong it should be  C:/wamp/www/mywebsitefolder/uploads/ ...

Comment: @max, it works in localhost as well if your setup virtual host and make the websitefolder as root directory. it works 100% in web server without any setups. Currently www is your root directory so project folder is hidden. Add manually the project folder name or setup the virtual host that's the solution for you. thanks!!

Comment: my thumbnail obeyed the width and height, but my source_image did not resize ... I was expecting that two things would happen: 1) the source image would be resized AND 2) a thumbnail with the `_thumb` token would be created ... ... ... but that would require 2 sets of width/height values ...

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to create a thumbnail.

```
function _create_thumbnail($fileName, $width, $height) 
{
    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    $config['image_library']  = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image']   = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. $fileName;       
    $config['create_thumb']   = TRUE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['width']          = $width;
    $config['height']         = $height;
    $config['new_image']      = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. $fileName;               
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    if (! $this->image_lib->resize()) { 
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    }        
}
```

Comment: Thank's, this ans perfect for me .. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is Okay but you need to do a small change.

```
 $this->load->library('image_lib');
 $this->image_lib->initialize($config_manip);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create more than one image using `resize()` method, you need to call `$this->image_lib->initialize($config);` each time you attempt a resize.

This tutorial solved it for me [Upload Image and Create Multiple Thumbnail Sizes in CodeIgniter](http://www.codersmount.com/2012/11/upload-image-and-create-multiple-thumbnail-sizes-in-codeigniter/)