# Codeiginter Multiple Image Resize Not Working As Expected

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, image-resizing

I'm trying to loop through an array of photos and resize each photo twice.  Once for a thumb and then once for full size image.  Everything works fine on the first loop, but the second, third, fourth, etc never have a thumbnail version created.  I cant figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Can anyone see my mistake from the code below?

```
$this->load->library('image_lib');
foreach( $photos as $current => $photo ) {                

    // Create Thumb
    $thumb_config = array();
    $thumb_config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $thumb_config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $thumb_config['source_image'] = $photo['full_path'];
    $thumb_config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $thumb_config['width'] = 550;
    $thumb_config['height'] = 550; 

    $this->image_lib->clear();
    $this->image_lib->initialize($thumb_config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
    // Resize Photo
    $resize_config = array();
    $resize_config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
    $resize_config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $resize_config['source_image'] = $photo['full_path'];
    $resize_config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $resize_config['width'] = 1500;
    $resize_config['height'] = 1500;

    $this->image_lib->clear();
    $this->image_lib->initialize($resize_config);
    $this->image_lib->resize(); 
}
```

Comment: Look into my answer ... [codeigniter resize image and create thumbnail](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11505260/782535)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try placing your `clear()`s after the `resize()` like this:

this is my current structure:

```
|--- assets
|    |--- images
|    |    |--- changed
|    |    |--- test.png
|    |    |--- test2.jpg
```

and after I run the code below, i have:

```
|--- assets
|    |--- images
|    |    |--- changed
|    |    |    |--- test.png
|    |    |    |--- test2.jpg
|    |    |    |--- test_thumb.png
|    |    |    |--- test2_thumb.jpg
|    |    |--- test.png
|    |    |--- test2.jpg
```

This is the code I used:

```
    $this->load->library('image_lib');

    $photos = array(
        array(
            "full_path" => "assets/images/",
            "name" => "test.png"
        ),
        array(
            "full_path" => "assets/images/",
            "name" => "test2.jpg"
        ),
    );
    foreach ($photos as $current => $photo) {
        // Create Thumb
        $thumb_config = array();
        $thumb_config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $thumb_config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $thumb_config['source_image'] = $photo['full_path'] . $photo['name'];
        $thumb_config['new_image'] = $photo['full_path'] . "changed/" . $photo['name'];
        $thumb_config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $thumb_config['width'] = 550;
        $thumb_config['height'] = 550;

        $this->image_lib->initialize($thumb_config);

        if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
            echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
        }
        $this->image_lib->clear();

        // Resize Photo
        $resize_config = array();
        $resize_config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
        $resize_config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $resize_config['source_image'] = $photo['full_path'] . $photo['name'];
        $resize_config['new_image'] = $photo['full_path'] . "changed/" . $photo['name'];
        $resize_config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $resize_config['width'] = 1500;
        $resize_config['height'] = 1500;

        $this->image_lib->initialize($resize_config);

        if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
            echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
        }
        $this->image_lib->clear();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still wont create the other thumbnails.  Its odd because it does the big resize, just wont make the thumbnails.

Comment: It never errors out.  I even did a $thumb = $this->image_lib->resize(); and then var_dump( $thumb ) and it return true like the function completed successfully.  I'm completely stumped on this one.

Comment: I just tried the code on my local machine, and it works just fine. I think the problem is that its replacing the original images and you want them to be copied. In that case you probably want to use this option: `$config['new_image']` and tell it where to store the image with the new name.

Comment: Thanks, using that param I was able to get it to work!