# Codeigniter image resize() thumbnail name should have same name

Tags: codeigniter

Here my controller file this working fine except in thumbs folder name get changed to converted_thumb
example:
my original image name is converted.jpg but in thumbs folder it save as converted_thumb so i want to remove _thumb from image name please solve this issue

```
public function do_upload() {
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads';  //  uploaded file store here
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg|gif';
        $config['max_size'] = ' 2097152';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if ($this->upload->do_upload()) {

            $data = $this->upload->data();

            //create  copy of image

            $configs['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $configs['source_image'] = $data['full_path'];
            $configs['new_image'] = 'uploads/thumbs/'; //resize image will save here
            $configs['create_thumb'] = 'false';
            $configs['width'] = '250';
            $configs['height'] = '250';
            $this->load->library('image_lib', $configs);
            $this->image_lib->resize();

            $image_name = $data['file_name'];
            //$full_path = $data['full_path'];
            $post = array(
                'product_name' => $image_name,
                'product_path' => $configs['new_image'].$image_name
            );

            $this->db->insert('project', $post);
        } else {
            echo $this->upload->display_errors();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Try [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) way.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you like the _thumbs from that? It is what it is for. Anyway do this.

```
rename("<?php echo base_url()?>/uploads/thumbs/YOUR_FILE_NAME_THUMBS", "<?php echo base_url()?>/uploads/thumbs/YOUR_FILE_NAME");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `thumb_marker` in your `$configs` array.

```
  $configs['image_library'] = 'gd2';
  $configs['source_image'] = $data['full_path'];
  $configs['new_image'] = 'uploads/thumbs/'; //resize image will save here
  $configs['create_thumb'] = 'false';
  $configs['thumb_marker'] = ''; //Add this in your config array empty string
```

Then '_thumb' will not add in your newly created files. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11505260/2385565) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `thumb_marker` to your config array and set it to `FALSE`

```
 $configs['image_library'] = 'gd2';
 $configs['source_image'] = $data['full_path'];
 $configs['new_image'] = 'uploads/thumbs/'; //resize image will save here
 $configs['create_thumb'] = 'false';
 $configs['thumb_marker'] = FALSE; //this will remove the "_thumb" to your thumb image name 
 $configs['width'] = '250';
 $configs['height'] = '250';
```